# Load a picturebox from a WIA ImageFile?

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox, wia

I've taken over a poorly designed project from a co-worker and am looking to load a picture box directly from the WIA command that just completed to take a picture from an attached USB camera.

The current implementation waits until the file has been written to disk, then displays it from there probably 
re-reading the file from disk.

```
Item item = d.ExecuteCommand(WIA.CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);

WIA.ImageFile imagefile = item.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG) as WIA.ImageFile;
```

I tried casting an Image to the given picture box without success

```
picBox.Image = (Image)imageFile;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WIA.ImageFile is a COM object wrapper, not a System.Drawing.Image.

You'll have to mess with WIA.ImageFile Save method with temporary files or try in-memory solution as shown here:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/wia-imagefile-system-drawing-image-t2321026.html

```
var imageBytes = (byte[])image.FileData.get_BinaryData(); 
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Thank you for the link Andrew, its much appreciated.

Comment: slap a using statement around that memory stream.