# How to show an image obtained from a scanner using WIA in a picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, wia

I want to display an image retrieved from a scanner in a picturebox. So far I have been able to do it saving the image to a temporary file:

```
 private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var fn = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        System.IO.File.Delete(fn);
        var image = Scanner.Scan();
        image.SaveFile(fn);
        _ScannedImage = Bitmap.FromFile(fn);
        pictureBoxMain.Image = _ScannedImage;
 }
```

Is there a way to convert the image data in the ImageFile class avoiding to save it to disk?

Comment: It is not impossible, support was added in WIA v2 with the IWiaTransfer and IWaiTransferCallback interfaces.  There is however nothing simple about using it in C#, these interfaces are only easy to use in a C++ program.  Code sample [is here](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/wia/datatransfer), consider wrapping it in a C++/CLI library to make it usable from your C# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the ImageFile to Image, and after that create a Bitmap object:

```
var myImage = (Image)imageFile;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myImage);
```

Therefore you don't have to save (as you requested) in path.

Please tell me if this works for you.

See this post about converting from ImageFile to Image:
[Load a picturebox from a WIA ImageFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413267/load-a-picturebox-from-a-wia-imagefile)

Comment: Thank you @C. Colin. As a fact, Scan() is retirning a WIA.ImageFile object wich is neither an Image nor a Bitmap :-&

Comment: @YvánEcarri I think you can convert from image file to image, or probably you could try to convert it directly to bitmap. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413267/load-a-picturebox-from-a-wia-imagefile

Comment: Thank you @C. Collin. I'll try that approach.

Answer (score 2):

As per @C. Colin comment, theres' a way to get the bitbitmap from the ImageFile using a memory stream:

```
var imageBytes = (byte[])image.FileData.get_BinaryData(); 
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

[Load a picturebox from a WIA ImageFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413267/load-a-picturebox-from-a-wia-imagefile)